# Is there a way to reference a function in a gs file in html on Apps Script?

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to reference a javascript function from a specific .gs file in Apps Script instead of incorporating the code in the script element. I'm planning on having a lot of code, so I want a separate file for it.
I have an html file created in Apps script (below).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>getElementById example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="para">Some text here</p>
  <button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
  <button onclick="changeColor('red');">red</button>
  <script src="uiTest.gs"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the script element to reference a file called 'uiTest.gs' to call the function 'changeColor(newColor)' (below)

```
function changeColor(newColor) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('para');
  elem.style.color = newColor;
}
```

My solution doesn't work. Is there a way to accomplish what I want, or will I be forced to put the code directly in the html? (I've tried google.script.run.changeColor(), didn't work)

Comment: You can create lots of files for your code and all of the files are accessible from your html via google.script.run.  You don't need to specify a file name.  The files are there just to make it easier to manage

Answer (score 0):

#### Using google.script.run to call server side functions from html/javascript

Javascript:

```
function changeColor(newColor) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('para');//para is the id of an html element
  elem.style.color = newColor;
  google.script.run.changeColor(newColor);//Calls a server side function which needs to be in a gs file 
}
```

[google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: So I just need to append google.script.run.[function(paramaters)] to any function I want to use in my html?
And I can just remove the script elements?

Comment: Yes without the square brackets and you may also use withSuccessHandler and withFailureHandler as well.  Any returned data is return via the withSuccessHandler clause which also allows the use of an anonymous function.

Comment: I've implemented the fix, but I've now run into a new problem where the javascript function fails on the error "document is not defined".

Comment: Well I just copied you code so what do you think is the problem now?

Comment: If you call a function using google.script.run, can you reference document in that function?

Comment: It didn't. I'm wondering if it's possible to pass document as a parameter

Comment: Is the function changeColor(newColor) { a javascript clientside function or a google apps script server side function?

Comment: Serverside function

Comment: So what does that tell you about the term document?

Comment: I realize that it's undefined. I'm just trying to ascertain whether or not it's possible to pass it as a parameter or not. Before, I just assumed that it was defined because the function was called within an html file, but I was wrong

Comment: Please read the comments I've added to my example and then tell me what the problem is.

Comment: I want to keep the html and javascript as separate as possible. My goal is to be able to reference a javascript function that utilizes the 'document' element from an html file, similar to how you can reference a function from a library, but within the same apps script file. I'm wondering if I can pass the 'document' element to a javascript function to make this possible, if there's some other way to reference 'document', or if this is just an exercise in futility.

Comment: Then you may wish to use templated html (look it up in the documentation)  google.script.run is for communicating from the browser i.e. clientside  to the server.  It allows you to call any server side function from javascript.  Or you can also call from an event like onClick.  I think I misunderstood your question in the beginning.

Comment: In any case, thanks for your help and patience